# Subset large dataframe over distinct singular character variable column value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, rbind, mutate

I'm still learning R and was wondering if I there was an elegant way of manipulating the below df to achieve df2.

I'm not sure if it's a loop that is supposed to be used for this, but basically I want to take a distinct on each V(X)_ID and it's associated V(X)_Z and return the first row V(X)_ID along with each subsequent occurrence of every other V(X)_Z (There are only two distinct types of V(X)_Z's).

This probably sounds confusing in words so hopefully an example from df to the desired df2 will assist in visualising what I'm trying to ask.

```
V1_ID <- c('A','B','I','N','G') 
V1_X <- c(1,2,3,4,5) 
V1_Y <- c(5.1,4.2,3.2,2.1,6.1) 
V1_Z <- c('Tom','Tom','Bill','Tom','Tom')

V2_ID <- c('B','D','E','F','G') 
V2_X <- c(2,5,6,7,5) 
V2_Y <- c(4.2,2,1,9,6.1) 
V2_Z <- c('Tom','Tom','Tom','Tom','Tom')

V3_ID <- c('C','B','A','N','G') 
V3_X <- c(0,2,1,4,5) 
V3_Y <- c(3,4.2,5.1,2.1,6.1) 
V3_Z <- c('Bill','Bill','Bill','Tom','Tom')

V4_ID <- c('N','G','C','B','A') 
V4_X <- c(4,5,0,2,1) 
V4_Y <- c(2,6.1,3,4.2,5.1) 
V4_Z <- c('Tom','Tom','Bill','Bill','Bill')

df <-data.frame(V1_ID,V1_X,V1_Y,V1_Z,V2_ID,V2_X,V2_Y,V2_Z,V3_ID,V3_X,V3_Y,V3_Z,V4_ID,V4_X,V4_Y,V4_Z)

V1_ID <- c('A','I',NA,NA) 
V1_X <- c(1,3,NA,NA) 
V1_Y <- c(5.1,3.2,NA,NA) 
V1_Z <- c('Tom','Bill',NA,NA)

V3_ID <- c('C','N','G',NA) 
V3_X <- c(0,4,5,NA) 
V3_Y <- c(3,2.1,6.1,NA) 
V3_Z <- c('Bill','Tom','Tom',NA)

V4_ID <- c('N','C','B','A') 
V4_X <- c(4,0,2,1) 
V4_Y <- c(2,3,4.2,5.1) 
V4_Z <- c('Tom','Bill','Bill','Bill')

df2 <- data.frame(V1_ID,V1_X,V1_Y,V1_Z,V3_ID,V3_X,V3_Y,V3_Z,V4_ID,V4_X,V4_Y,V4_Z)
```

You can see that V2 has been excluded from the desired dataframe because there are no occurrences of other distinct V2_Z aside from "Tom".

Your assistance is much appreciated as I have hundreds of these types of columns in this type of format and approaching it from a manual standpoint is very draining.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a good idea to bring this data first in long format and then think about what you want to filter. Below is a first approach, maybe you can elaborate a bit more on the exact conditions you want to filter.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = c("no", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(.*)_([^_]+)$",
               values_transform = as.character)

df_long %>% group_by(no) %>% 
  # here we filter all groups `no` which only have one value in `Z`:
  filter(n_distinct(Z) > 1) %>% 
  filter(c(Z[1] == first(Z), Z[-1] != first(Z))) 

#> # A tibble: 9 × 5
#> # Groups:   no [3]
#>   no    ID    X     Y     Z    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 V1    A     1     5.1   Tom  
#> 2 V3    C     0     3     Bill 
#> 3 V4    N     4     2     Tom  
#> 4 V1    I     3     3.2   Bill 
#> 5 V4    C     0     3     Bill 
#> 6 V3    N     4     2.1   Tom  
#> 7 V4    B     2     4.2   Bill 
#> 8 V3    G     5     6.1   Tom  
#> 9 V4    A     1     5.1   Bill
```

Data from OP

```r
V1_ID <- c('A','B','I','N','G') 
V1_X <- c(1,2,3,4,5) 
V1_Y <- c(5.1,4.2,3.2,2.1,6.1) 
V1_Z <- c('Tom','Tom','Bill','Tom','Tom')

V2_ID <- c('B','D','E','F','G') 
V2_X <- c(2,5,6,7,5) 
V2_Y <- c(4.2,2,1,9,6.1) 
V2_Z <- c('Tom','Tom','Tom','Tom','Tom')

V3_ID <- c('C','B','A','N','G') 
V3_X <- c(0,2,1,4,5) 
V3_Y <- c(3,4.2,5.1,2.1,6.1) 
V3_Z <- c('Bill','Bill','Bill','Tom','Tom')

V4_ID <- c('N','G','C','B','A') 
V4_X <- c(4,5,0,2,1) 
V4_Y <- c(2,6.1,3,4.2,5.1) 
V4_Z <- c('Tom','Tom','Bill','Bill','Bill')

df <-data.frame(V1_ID,V1_X,V1_Y,V1_Z,V2_ID,V2_X,V2_Y,V2_Z,V3_ID,V3_X,V3_Y,V3_Z,V4_ID,V4_X,V4_Y,V4_Z)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the input, I'm looking to add some extra rows into your answer. There should be an additional "3" entry with C_ID as G, C_X as 5, C_Y as 6.1 and C_Z as Tom. Similarly, there should be another two more "4" entries. D_ID (B,A) D_X (2,1) D_Y (4.2,5.1) D_Z (Bill Bill). Essentially I'm after every other occurrence of Tom or Bill if the first entry is Bill or Tom.

Comment: @bilmawr I really have problems getting my head around your filter logic. If you really want "every other occurrence of Tim or Bill if the first entry is Bill or Tim" then we can just drop the last  `distinct(no, Z, .keep_all = TRUE) ` statement, or?

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. Sorry I know this sounds confusing. Removing the last will for example in V1 have two occurrences for Tom when I'm after only the first occurence.

Comment: In a nutshell if the first V(X)_Z is "Tom" then return the first Tom and all other occurrences of "Bill" and similarly vice versa.  If the first V(X)_Z is "Bill" then return the first Bill and all other occurrences of "Tom". Thanks for putting up with me.